Unable to access session data in Express using express-session
I have implemented user authentication in my Node.js application using express-session and connect-session-sequelize to manage sessions and store session data in my MySQL database. Upon successful login, I set the session data like this:
req.session.user = {
  id: user.id,
  email: user.email
};

However, when I try to access this session data in subsequent requests, particularly from a Nuxt.js frontend using Axios for API calls, I'm unable to retrieve the session data (req.session.user is always undefined).
Here's how I've configured my server-side code:
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import { sequelize } from './Database/Models/index';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import session from 'express-session';
import usersRoute from './Routers/usersRoute';
import checkAuthenticated from './Middlewares/checkAuthenticated';

const app = express();

app.use(cookieParser())
const SequelizeStore = require("connect-session-sequelize")(session.Store);
var myStore = new SequelizeStore({
  db: sequelize,
    checkExpirationInterval: 15 * 60 * 1000, 
  expiration: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000  
});

app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'secret',
    cookie: {
      secure: false
    },
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    unset: 'destroy'
  }),
);

myStore.sync();

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: [
      'http://localhost:3000',
      'https://localhost:3000'
    ],
    credentials: true,
    exposedHeaders: ['set-cookie']
}))

const checkAuthenticated = (req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
  if (req.session && req.session.user) {
    console.log(req.session.user)
    res.json({ loggedIn: true });
    next();
  } else {
    console.log(req.session)
    res.json({ loggedIn: false });
  }
};

export default checkAuthenticated;

export const loginUser = async (req: any, res: any) => {
  try {
    const { error, value } = loginSchema.validate(req.body);
    if (error) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: error.details[0].message });
    }
    const user = await serviceLoginUser(value);

    req.session.user = {
            id: user.id,
            email: user.email,
        };
    res.status(200).json({Login: true, user: req.session.user});
  } catch (error: any) {
    const statusCode = error.code || 500;
    console.log(error.message)
    res.status(statusCode).json({ error: error.message });
  }
}

And here's how I'm making the API call from my Nuxt.js frontend using Axios:
<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue';
  import axios from 'axios';

  axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

  const email = ref('');
  const password = ref('');
  const showPassword = ref(false);
  const errors = ref('');
  
  const togglePasswordVisibility = () => {
    showPassword.value = !showPassword.value;
  };
  
  const handleSubmit =  async () => {
    try {
      await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/users/signin", {
        email: email.value,
        password: password.value
      }
      , {
      withCredentials: true
      });
      await navigateTo('/')
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
</script>

Could someone please guide me on what could be causing this issue and how to properly access session data in Express when using express-session?

Double-check that it works with some sort of Postman first. Then give a try to an on-click call rather. Probably messed up by the lifecycle here.

Thank you for your suggestions, Kissu. I forgot to mention that it works fine when tested with Insomnia, but encounters issues when accessed via the browser. I did try implementing the onClick call as you recommended, but unfortunately, I still face the same problem.

If it works well with Insomnia, it is not a backend issue. Do you see any error in the console/network tab regarding Nuxt? Also give maybe a try to $fetch since you're using Nuxt: https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/data-fetching Also, maybe check on the backend if the payload you're sending from the front-end is maybe a bit different somehow?
